# Recommendation for Phone Verification Web Service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Goal**: I have a business database website full of businesses. Business owners want to claim ownership of their business records. I need to verify that they own the business by calling the phone number on file with a randomly generated code which they will then submit to my site, thus making them Ruler Of Their Kingdom and Master Of Their Domain.

I need a service service that would facilitate this by exposing an API that allows me to provide it a phone number and a 6 digit code at which point it will call the given phone number and tell the user the given code.

**Platform**: Rails 3

**Problem**: Based on my Googling, there are a plethora of services that provide this functionality and they all generally look to do the same thing for about the same price. I have no idea how to pick one.

**How you can help**: Suggest a service you've used that you liked.

My main concern is finding a reliable company that is established and not likely to go anywhere anytime soon. I have no problem writing an API wrapper myself if the service is awesome, but obviously a service that already has a Ruby Gem would get an edge. Price is not really too big of a concern because this will be somewhat low-volume. **If by any chance there is such a service that also does snail-mail verification (should the business owner prefer to receive a post-card with their code) that would be a HUGE bonus**

I've already found these services that seem like potential possibilities:

1. http://called.in/
2. https://www.tropo.com/
3. http://www.twilio.com/
4. http://www.onverify.com/

As always, thank you to everyone in advance for sharing your expertise!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twilio probably has exactly what you are looking for. I have used Twilio in a C#/.NET app and it was very easy to use. I'd imagine it would be equally easy in RoR.

Here's a link to the Twilio documentation on speaking over a voice call: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say

Twilio also provides 'widgets', called Twimlets, that you can call directly, avoiding the need to interface with Twilio directly.

http://labs.twilio.com/twimlets/

Here's a Twimlet that will just play a message during an outbound call: http://labs.twilio.com/twimlets/echo

Edited to add a link to the ruby gem: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby

Comment: Twilio was definitely the front-runner for me in my evaluation, the only thing that put me off (slightly) was that the last commit to their ruby lib was almost 6 months ago.

Comment: I probably wouldn't worry about that too much. I'm sure the base functionality works, and based on your requirements above, you probably shouldn't need much.

Comment: As a followup I implemented Twilio today and it was ridiculously straight forward. So far so good, thanks for the recommendation!